# Inserir no começo de uma fila circular

Tags: c, array, fila

Estou trabalhando num programa de fila circular onde desejo implementar uma função de "furar fila", onde o usuário insere um número e este número deveria ser inserido nos espaços da fila anteriores a f.com.
Porém a lógica que implementei não pareceu funcionar muito bem, gostaria de pedir ajuda com ideias ou sobre o que fazer efetivamente no código.
Declarei a minha fila assm:

```
struct circular
{   int com;
    int fim;
    int total;
    int memo[MAX];
}; 

typedef struct circular circular;
int main ()
{
    struct circular F;
    F.com = 0;
    F.total = 0;
    F.fim = -1;

}
```

Deste modo eu declaro a fila e a inicializo na main, a função que tentei criar porém não funcionou foi esta:

```
void furafila(struct circular *F, int x)
{  int aux,aux2;
    aux = F->com;
    F->fim++;
    if(F->fim == MAX)
   {
      F->fim = 0;
   }
    aux2=F->fim;
    F->memo[F->fim] = x;
    F->com = aux2;
    F->fim = aux-1;
    F->total++;

}
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Mas o campo `com` representa o que ? e qual a diferença entre `fim` e `total` ? Os nomes dos campos não estão muito claros.

Comment: com = começo da fila
fim representa o final da fila
e o total é só uma variável para obter o número total de elementos na fila, auxiliando na função de exibir.

Comment: "este número deveria ser inserido nos espaços da fila anteriores a f.com" - da posição `0` até `f.com` ? Tem como mostrar um exemplo de antes de depois de utilizar o `furafila` ?

Comment: Por exemplo tenho a fila com os índices e numeros:
I = início, F= Final
0   1   2 
22 14 10
I           F

Fura fila com o número 72

0     1    2    3
72  22  14  10
I                   F